# pre and post PSF import in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, configuration

I wanted to do some custom actions before and after importing PSF file in eclipse. For example, before import check whether PDE is installed and after set target platform in plugin development to some value. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

In modern Eclipse version, [Oomph](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.oomph) can be used to such extents: you can create and share setup files that can create a shared environment, including the installation of files using a P2 director task, set up a target platform using a Targlet task and import psf files using the Project Set Import task.

A lot of projects are already using it at eclipse.org (with open source setup files), so there are a large number of examples you can look at; and the developers are very responsive in case of problems.

The tool can sometimes be a bit hard to figure out, but it is still very useful in a lot of circumstances.